# Was StratifiedKFold really used by GridSearchCV?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

After using GridSearchCV,  is there any way to find out if StratifiedKFold was really used instead of KFold?

As an estimator I used SVC (Support Vector Machine) with a cv=10.

I know that the documentation (scikit-learn Version 0.21.3) says that StratifiedKFold is actually used in this case. I, however, suspect that this may not have been the case.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure, you can always enter into the github repo and read the code. [Take a look here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L841), where the function is defined.

Also, exactly in this [line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c42d54b26137a456c510c5fdba1ba23e0/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2006) you have your answer. Yes it does.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I saved the results including the GridSearchCV instance as a pickle file.
Is there no way to find out if StratifiedKFold was actually used by accessing this file?

Comment: Hm I do not really understand what do you mean, but in order to do this comparison, try to do two executions, with cv=None and the other with cv=5. If the results are the same, it means you are using always the KFold class (the cv=5 means the sklearn library should use stratifiedkfold).